# Webform get email addresses from entity select unlimited

Tags: webforms, 9

I have an Entity select element that references a role. The element is unlimited so multiple users can be selected at one time. I need to get each selected user's email address.

Using a computed twig element, I can get the email address of the first selected user with `webform_token()`:

```
{% set reviewer_email_address = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:entity:mail]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{{ reviewer_email_address }}
```

Something simple like:

```
{{ data.reviewer.0 }}
{{ data.reviewer.1 }}
```

prints the user id of the users. So the user entities are present.

How do I get the email address from `{{ data.reviewer.0 }}`?

Comment: You can use debugger and view data.reviewer variable. If you use twig tweak module you can use {{ drupal_breakpoint() }} for debug twig templates

Answer (score 0):

This is a non DRY solution:

```
{% set reviewer_0 = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:0:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% set reviewer_1 = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:1:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% set reviewer_2 = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:2:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% set reviewer_3 = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:3:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% set reviewer_4 = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:4:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% set reviewer_5 = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:reviewer:5:entity:mail:clear]', webform_submission, [], options) %}
{% if reviewer_0|length %}{{ reviewer_0 }}{% else %}{% endif %}
{% if reviewer_1|length %},{{ reviewer_1 }}{% else %}{% endif %}
{% if reviewer_2|length %},{{ reviewer_2 }}{% else %}{% endif %}
{% if reviewer_3|length %},{{ reviewer_3 }}{% else %}{% endif %}
{% if reviewer_4|length %},{{ reviewer_4 }}{% else %}{% endif %}
{% if reviewer_5|length %},{{ reviewer_5 }}{% else %}{% endif %}
```

with
"Remove whitespace around the"
computed value and between HTML tags

and
"Automatically update the computed value using Ajax".
Checked

in the computed twig element.

The twig needs to be improved in case there are more than 6 reviewers and for DRY principle.